# How to pass Data Between multiple routes in express?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, session, mongoose

```
 app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local",), function (req, res) {
  const user = new Model({
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password,
  });

  req.login(user, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("wrong password");
    } else {
      passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function () {
        res.redirect("/admin");
      });
    }
  });
});

app.post("/admin", function (req, res) {
 
  Model.findOne({username: "siddharth"}).exec(function(err, foundList){
  if(foundList)
  {
    const list = new linkModel({
      linkTitle: req.body.linkTitle,
      linkUrl: req.body.linkUrl,
     
    });
   
    foundList.links.push(list);
    foundList.save();
   
  
   res.redirect("/admin");
  }
  else
    {res.send("redirect to home page and then login");
    res.redirect("/login");

    }
  

  });
});
```

How can i pass the username when authenticated from login routeto other route(admin) where mongoose query is defined findone?
As i have defined it explicitly.

Or i simple terms how can i pass the data among routes ?

Answer (score -1):

You can't. Instead use a middleware to do the checks you want and pass on the result to another middleware or return the response in case of error.

Comment: I just want to push the data to user collections when he logs in.As you can see i have specifed my name instead of fetching username when the user login.

Can you eloborate more about middleware thing